# NSPredicate count > 0 on many to many to many relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate

I have a three level hierarchy of objects in CoreData:
Let say Entity **A** has a set of Entities **B** and Entity **B** has a set of Entities **C**. (A many-to-many B and B many-to-many C)

I want to get all the entities A such that the As have Bs and Cs.
I am trying to use a predicate when fetching Entities A: `NSPredicate(format: "ANY bs.cs.@count > 0")'` but i am getting this error: `Unsupported function expression count: (bs.cs)`

Any idea on how to correctly write this query?

Comment: If I do, I will fetch all the Entity As out, and `forin` to filter out the correct ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "ANY" operator does not work with nested to-many relationships,
therefore you need a "SUBQUERY" (which unfortunately is not very well
documented). Something like this should work:

```
NSPredicate(format:"SUBQUERY(bs, $b, $b.cs.@count != 0).@count != 0")
```

The `SUBQUERY(..)` part returns all related `B` objects which have at least one related `C` object. The final `.@count != 0` part checks that there is
at least one related `B` object with this property.